# Add 'Open Powershell here as admin' option to folder context menu

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have been looking for a way to open an elevated Powershell prompt from Windows Explorer directly, via the context menu of the folder I want to open the prompt in.
I'm using Windows 10 and all the examples I've seen so far have been for older versions of Windows.  I previously had this working on Windows 8.1, but the update to 10 broke it.  I even got this working on Windows 10 briefly, but an update broke it again (Dec 2015).

Does anyone know the *correct* way to add this feature to Windows?  Or is it doomed to be overwritten by future updates to Windows?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the only way I know of to currently add this feature to context menus in Windows Explorer:

**[Run this script in an elevated powershell prompt]**

```
$menu = 'Open Windows PowerShell Here as Administrator'
$command = "$PSHOME\powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile -Command ""Set-Location '%V'"""

'directory', 'directory\background', 'drive' | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$_\shell" -Name runas\command -Force |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name '(default)' -Value $command -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Path {$_.PSParentPath} -Name '(default)' -Value $menu -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name HasLUAShield -Value ''
}
```

This script taken from the following link:

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/25/pstip-how-to-start-an-elevated-powershell-from-windows-explorer/

I'm 99% certain that this was the way I did it before the latest Windows patch 'removed' my registry setting (it also removed some other customisations, like numlock boot status, but that is less annoying).

If anyone knows a better approach; i.e. that won't be volatile, then please let me know and I'll accept that answer.

Comment: Windows 10 certainly is a pain with UAC. Even "disabled" it's a constant headache ._. The only reason I haven't gone back to Windows 7 is because I now have 4 screens.

Comment: Remove the `-NoProfile` switch to get your profile loaded automatically when you launch the prompt.

Comment: Note that if you want to add a "Run script as admin" context-menu option for the ps1 files themselves, section 2 of this answer shows how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Comment: This works great as of Windows 1909. It opens the blue window version of PowerShell. Some other solutions open a small, black background window which doesn't work as well.

Comment: @usr FYI the black window is actually cmd prompt, the blue is powershell, they are similar but not the same.  [more info](https://www.howtogeek.com/163127/how-powershell-differs-from-the-windows-command-prompt/)

Answer (score 2):

For people who want to open `Powershell` in elevated `Windows Terminal`, here is Astravagrant's modified [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1014211).

**[Run this script in an elevated powershell prompt]**

```
$menu = 'Open in Terminal as Admin'
$command = 'wt.exe -p "Windows PowerShell" -d "%V"'

'directory', 'directory\background', 'drive' | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$_\shell" -Name runas\command -Force |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name '(default)' -Value $command -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Path {$_.PSParentPath} -Name '(default)' -Value $menu -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name HasLUAShield -Value ''
}
```

I modified `$command` to open `wt.exe` (Windows Terminal).

`-p "Windows PowerShell"` flag allows you to choose WT's profile name you want to use. If you want to open WT with default profile, remove `-p "..."` flag.

`-d "%V"` flag refers to current folder location

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing it like this. It is part of a little menu I made. Edit it to your liking:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\OAPS.Tools]
"ImpliedSelectionModel"=dword:00000001
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-5373"
"ExplorerCommandHandler"="{BF0AC53F-D51C-419F-92E3-2298E125F004}"
@="Admin Pshell Here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of the reg file I use to add both CMD and POWERSHELL to the BACKGROUND context menu of any folder in Windows 10:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Add_Open_CMD_and_Powershell_to_Context_Menu.reg

;Right-Click Background only

;CMD Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\01MenuCmd] "MUIVerb"="Command Prompts" "Icon"="cmd.exe" "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\01MenuCmd] "MUIVerb"="Command Prompts" "Icon"="cmd.exe" "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open] "MUIVerb"="Command Prompt" "Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command] @="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas] "MUIVerb"="Command Prompt Elevated" "Icon"="cmd.exe" "HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas\command] @="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

; PowerShell

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell] "MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts" "Icon"="powershell.exe" "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell] "MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts" "Icon"="powershell.exe" "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open] "MUIVerb"="PowerShell" "Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command] @="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas] "MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated" "Icon"="powershell.exe" "HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command] @="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"
```